# How to parse JSON results from Unirest call in python?

Tags: python, json, unirest

```
      response_post =unirest.get("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms?feedtype=sjson",headers={
"X-Mashape-Key": "key",
"Accept": "application/json"},)
```

how to parse response_post as json result?

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding .body to the end of the request?

The docs seem pretty clear - http://unirest.io/python.html

```
response_post =unirest.get("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms?feedtype=sjson",headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "key",
    "Accept": "application/json"},).body
```

Comment: added .body and getting the same result. How to iterate over to get json datas? like: for i in x: for ii in i: print ii,,, that should give me one particular item. It ain't working the way I am thinking.

Comment: Generally you want to try print(response_post), then for i in response post: print(i) This helps you determine what the contents of the variable are, and what you can do with it. - But that being said, you need to update your post with the new code, and what output you are getting so we don't have to guess at what the problem is.

Comment: If you're really getting  json back from that request, you're going to end up with an object that's iterable. Paste the results of print(response_post) and I can help you understand how that works.